# I have an answer that is not showing for my question or the count of answers is not correct

Tags: support, answers

My in-box and questions tab shows that my question has an answer but when I actually go to the question there isn't an answer. From what I can see of the answer it may be spam... is this a problem with a spam filter or automated removal?

Here is what it looks like on my questions tab:

[image]

Here is what the question page looks like:

[image]

And this is what my inbox had:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The answer was likely removed automatically by the system after gathering a number of spam flags, as indicated by the [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) having the last activity on your question.

The denormalized answer count can get out of sync when this happens (typically when the user who posted the spam is also deleted), but it will eventually be corrected by an automated maintenance process that runs daily.

As for the inbox item, sometimes entries corresponding to deleted items aren't always removed. I've found this seems to often be the case if you've already read the entry, but that may have just been coincidence. There are a number of posts here on Meta about that topic, but I'm not sure if it's been determined conclusively whether or not that's actually the intended behaviour.